# HTML5 Storing Data through page navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

I have a project I am currently working on where it has a number of stored values that the user can select. The application has a number of pages and I have come across something called parsing data and recalling.

I am looking to save out the information when the user changes the values. Bit hard to explain so I have included a picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebg20.jpg

So the user can change the POWER, Spot Diameter, Exposure Time and Radius, then when the page changes those values can be recalled again.

I am using Javascript variables with jquery, as i want this application to be cross platform and be able to run on an ipad.

Comment: Your "question" is a bit vague.  If you describe the problem, and the specify a single question, "how can i..." rather than simply stating a problem, then you may get more answers quicker...

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to store and retrieve data is using cookies.  jQuery.cookie (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) is probably your best bet.  It's very easy to use, reliable, and takes away all the complexities of it.  Make sure you use the `path:`  variable to save them to `/` or something.

You can also save data to HTML5 '(local)storage'.  http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html has an introduction, although it's a bit over detailed in the history.

To be honest, cookies are probably the easiest way to go.

If you want to store data in such a way that people can read the *same* data from different computers, then you'll need to store it in a database (or whatever) on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Like Daniel mentioned you could use cookies, altough nowadays you're expected to show a statement that you're using cookies and describe what they're for which leaves users usually doubtful in these "oh noes! my privacy!"-times ;) Ideally you could use "html5" localstorage instead, as the rules on local storage are considerably more vague ;)

However, perhaps this is overthinking the design, you mention you have only a handful of variables, if these are shared throughout all the pages of your application, why not make them part of a query string in the URL ?

You can append these variables using either the good 'ol hashtag or ?-parameters, like so:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/somepage/?power=500&counter=28&spot=200&exposure=20&radius=1600
```

Then when your page loads you can use Javascript to check whether these parameters are present (this site has some excellent examples on how to [retrieve query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)). This also has the benefit that you could share this URL as a deeplink and it will set these values automatically for the visitor (should this be desired, of course ;))